# Axios Patch Request showing params as undefined in the backed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, frontend, backend

I want to update data in the server with a Axios Patch call and there seems to be some error in the code which i cant seem to figure out. Help me out please.

Node express API call in the backend:

```
router.patch('/up',async (req, res) => {



 try{

const id =  req.query.userid;                        // User objectid here.

console.log(req.body)

console.log(req.query.userid)

   const result= User.findById(id, (error, foundUser) => {
      if (foundUser) {
        const { products } = foundUser;

        const filteredproducts = products.filter((item) => {
          return item._id!= req.body.body._id;                //product array object id
        });
        while (foundUser.products.length > 0) {
          foundUser.products.pop();
        }

        foundUser.products = filteredproducts;

            foundUser.products.push({
            brandname: req.body.brandname,
            productname: req.body.productname,
            quantity: req.body.quantity,
            price: req.body.price,
            description: req.body.description
        });
        foundUser.save();
        
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('User not found')
      }
    })
    res.status(200).send("update successfull");
}
catch(err){
    res.status(403).send('update unsuccessfull')
    console.log(err)
}

  })
```

Userschema in db:

```
const userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true

},
place: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
products:[
    {
        brandname: {
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        productname:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        quantity:{
            type:Number,
            required:true
        },
        price:{
            type:Number,
            required:true
        },
        description:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        }
        
    }
]
,
tokens:
    [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
    ]

    })

const User = mongoose.model('USER', userschema)
```

Front end API code

```
    const updateproduct = async(req,res) => {
    console.warn(values.brandname, values.productname,values.quantity, values.price, 
     values.description)

    console.warn("userlogin is:,",userid)                // User object id here.

    const _id=id;                                        // Product object id here

    await axios.patch(`http://localhost:5000/up`,{

    headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {brandname,productname,quantity,price,description,_id},  //getting the values of all the fields here. checked by console logging them.
        params:{
            'userid':userid
        }
    },
    { withCredentials: true })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            navigate('/listproduct')
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })

   }
```

Sorry if my code look really bad. I am new to React and node.

All i wanna do is edit the product details of a product by the product objectid and store it in the db.

Any other method other than this is also fine. I am stuck with this problem for more than 2 days coudn't find a solution till now. Any help is much Appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have tried to update the code but still the same errors.

**backend API**

```
router.patch('/up',async (req, res) => {



 try{

const id =  req.query.userid;

console.log("user id is",id)

console.log("req.body",req.body.body.brandname)

 const result= User.findById(id, (error, foundUser) => {
      if (foundUser) {
        const { products } = foundUser;

        const filteredexpenses = products.filter((item) => {
          return item._id!= req.body.body._id;
        });
        while (foundUser.products.length > 0) {
          foundUser.products.pop();
        }

        foundUser.products = filteredexpenses;

            foundUser.products.push({
            brandname: req.body.body.brandname,
            productname: req.body.body.productname,
            quantity: req.body.body.quantity,
            price: req.body.body.price,
            description: req.body.body.description
        });
        foundUser.save();
        
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('User not found')
      }
    })
    res.status(200).send("update successfull");
}
catch(err){
    res.status(403).send('update unsuccessfull')
    console.log(err)
}

  })
```

**Front end API**

```
const updateproduct = async(req,res) => {
    console.warn(values.brandname, values.productname,values.quantity, values.price, values.description)

    console.warn("userlogin is:,",userid)

    const _id=id;

    await axios.patch(`http://localhost:5000/up`,{

    headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: 


{'brandname':brandname,'productname':productname,'quantity':quantity,'price':price,'description':description,'_id':_id},
        params:{
            'userid':userid
        }
    },
    { withCredentials: true })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            navigate('/listproduct')
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })

}
```

**Result on console log is**

```
User id is undefined
req.body adidas                       //brandname
User not found
```

Comment: What specifically is `null`, things like `req.body.brandname`? Your front end code seems to be attempting to just passing in the _values_ (is `data` even valid JSON and getting constructed correctly?). Maybe the `data` line needs to be something like `data: { 'brandname': brandname, ... }`?

Comment: after i send the data from front-end to back-end the request.query.userid is showing undefined. i dont know why. 

The data is working good as i console logged it in the backend and its showing there.

The only thing that's not working for me is 'req.query.userid.'  as i console log it in backend its showing undefined. but in front-end if i console log it its showing the id.

Comment: What is the output of the `console.log(req.body)` line that you have in there? Can you add that to the question? Also, did you try making the adjustment I described above to add the field names to the payload?

Comment: @user20042973 I have tried the above changes...but still the error continues. I have changed some code in the backend too. Please check out the edits.